# With pytorch module,will computation graph be overrode when forward() was invoke multiple times before backward()?

Tags: pytorch

I found a line of code:

```
out_a, out_p, out_n = model(data_a), model(data_p), model(data_n)
```

in:https://github.com/liorshk/facenet_pytorch/blob/master/train_triplet.py

as you can see that the "forward()" is invoked multiple times before "backward()", question are:

1, Will next invoking override previous computation graph?

2, In my test, the GPU consumption will increase accordingly, so even overriding happened,GPUu memory leaking happens, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

No, the graph is not over-ridden by different calls to forward.
Every time you call forward, computations are added to the graph and hence gpu consumption increases.

When you call `model.zero_grad()` graphs are cleared.